# zend 2 application from svn check out is not run in xampp

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I check out zend2 application from svn and run this in xampp but the application is not loaded. Give following warning in firefox.

"The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

The application is run fine in other machine. what is the reason for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a routing issue. I can only guess: Check if your local xampp is configured correctly, I remember an issue where rewrite rules were broken when switching from linux to Windows in vhost. Also make sure hidden files like .htaccess were synced in svn.